# asp.net Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have got this error

> Unable to connect to the remote server

when I call the web service from the windows service. But I can visit this web service through IE and I also wrote another console application to call the web service and it works fine, too.

The exception infomation is below:

> A socket operation was attempted to an
>   unreachable network 127.0.0.1:8888

Here is my code:

```
WebImageSVC webSvc = new WebImageSVC();  
ConfigManager.LoadConfigManager();  
webSvc.Url = ConfigManager.WebSvcAddress;  
webSvc.Proxy = null;  
webSvc.CanUpload(0, "");
```

I try many methods, like turn off the firewall and anti-virus software, set the web services proxy property to null. but still cannot solve this issue.

Is there anyone meet this problem ? thanks a lot.

Comment: i means when the windows service call the web service then have that exception.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it is a permissions issue.  Try using OpenSCManager to change the credentials of your Windows service to run under a user that can access the Web service.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681921(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681921%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: can you tell me more details about how to change the credentials of my windows service?

Comment: thanks @light, i have just found out the problem and it is true that is the permissions issue. thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are redirected to `127.0.0.1:8888` is mostly used by system proxies. These are programs for anonymous surfing or web debugging like Fiddler. Close the proxy program.

Comment: yes,i also guess that might be the proxy problems.i had installed the Fiddler, but it is closed. and you can see my code:webSvc.Proxy = null; is there any method to check the proxy program run anonymous?

Comment: What is obvious, you are redirecting to proxy address, which means a program has registered itself as system proxy. Check task manager, maybe fiddler is not closed completely and is not responding. Also maybe there's a firefox or IE addon which turns it on automatically when using browser. I'm sure your code works on another machine. This is a OS issue not programming.